# Request data input is not working after ajax call using asp classic

Tags: ajax, request, asp-classic

Data is not saved when button SAVE(trnSR.asp) is clicked because it request empty value in ajaxtrnSR.asp. I have tried using request.QueryString but still not working. Here is my code:

**page: trnSR.asp**

```
function FunSave(){
var strSORNum           = document.mainform.cboSOR.value;

xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null){
    alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
    return;
}
var url="./ajaxtrnSR.asp";  
url=url+"?actionmode=UPDATE&a="+strSORNum;

xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

}

**page: ajaxtrnSR.asp**

```
<%  nExample =request.QueryString("txtExample)%>

<td><input type ="textbox" name ="txtExample" style="width:100%" value ="example" readOnly></td>
```

Issue: variable xExample is empty value. Can I retrieve value in ajax page or I need to pass the value to trnSR.asp ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the value by Request.QueryString in ajaxtrnSR.asp you need to pass it in the url of trnSR.asp:

```
url=url+"?actionmode=UPDATE&a="+strSORNum+"&txtExample="+txtExample;
```

But when i see ajaxtrnSR.asp i am a little confused because it seems that you want to get the value from this same page. In that case you needed to surround this input tag with a form with method="get" OR you put a form with method="post" and retrieve the value with Request.Form.